# React Hooks useEffect - wait on function which is modifying state before executing next function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

How can I make one function wait for another which is updating the state?

**Example:**

on submission a form calls `trainData`. TrainData needs to be processed first. it uses `data` array which comes from `props` which HAS data.

**Problem:**

In `trainData`'s if check, `inputMatrix` and `outputMatrix` are both empty (I am guessing because they need to be updated first but trainData doesn't wait for that).

How can I solve this? I think I need to use `useEffect` but what exactly am I waiting on?

```
  const [inputMatrix, setInputMatrix] = useState([]);
  const [outputMatrix, setOutputMatrix] = useState([]);

  const processData = () => {
    const inputMatrixTemp = [];
    const outputMatrixTemp = [];
    data.forEach((patientRecord) => {
      const record = Object.values(patientRecord);
      inputMatrixTemp.push(record.slice(1, record.length));
      outputMatrixTemp.push([record[0]]);
    });
    setInputMatrix(inputMatrixTemp);
    setOutputMatrix(outputMatrixTemp);
  };

  const trainData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    processData();
    if (inputMatrix.length > 0 && outputMatrix.length > 0) {
      ...crazy stuff happens here
    }
  };

<form onSubmit={trainData} className="main__form">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (inputMatrix.length > 0 && outputMatrix.length > 0) {
      ...your crazy stuff here
  }
}, [inputMatrix, outputMatrix]); // will only run when changing this
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (inputMatrix.length > 0 && outputMatrix.length > 0) {
      ...crazy stuff happens here
   }
}, [inputMatrix, outputMatrix])
```

But you have to call your `processData` in your form's onSubmit.

```
<form onSubmit={processData} className="main__form">
```